# ffmpeg showspectrumpic fscale=log not rendering Right audio channel

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, lavfilters

I am running these two command and getting surprising result on the second one.

The first command produce (fscale=lin):

```
ffmpeg -i stereo-test.mp3 -lavfi showspectrumpic=s=600x600:mode=separate:fscale=lin:scale=log spect_lin.bmp
```

[spect_lin.bmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkNfS.png)

but the second command produce (fscale=log):

```
ffmpeg -i stereo-test.mp3 -lavfi showspectrumpic=s=600x600:mode=separate:fscale=log:scale=log spect_log.bmp
```

[spect_log.bmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjvp4.png)

Sadly on the **second image, the right channel is missing** and I cannot figure out why.
Any idea or suggestion would be awesome :)

Thanks !

PS: You can find my test file here: [stereo-test.mp3](http://www.aoakley.com/articles/stereo-test.mp3)

I am using: `ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers`

EDIT: does not work using `ffmpeg version 4.3.1-4ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers` too.

Comment: Also happens with showspectrum filter. Get build from current git master branch (either [download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)) then submit a [bug report](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/) showing your command, the complete console output, and a link to the input file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will submit a bug report.

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9061

Comment: You'll probably be asked to show the output from a build from the git master branch because development is so active and releases are always outdated.